# Pass Generics argument to method of class or cast result of method to given Generics type?

Tags: java, generics, type-erasure

I need to return a result from a method where the returned object itself should have the same type as the Generics parameter. This seems to be more difficult than I thought.

Here is a simplified example:

```
import android.content.Context;

public class PreferencesManager<T>
{
    private EncryptingPreferencesManager<T> encryptingPreferencesManager;

    public PreferencesManager(Context context)
    {
        encryptingPreferencesManager = new EncryptingPreferencesManager<>(context);
    }

    public T getPreferencesData(String identifier)
    {
        T data = encryptingPreferencesManager.getData(identifier);

    return data;
    }
}
```

...and the instantiated class:

```
public class EncryptingPreferencesManager<T>
{
    private Context context;

    public EncryptingPreferencesManager(Context context)
    {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public T getData(String identifier) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException
    {
    //do some stuff and get the content, which is a JSON 

        final T result = (T)JsonMapper.fromJsonToJavaObject(decryptedJson, ??????.class);

        return result;
    }
}
```

This is the JsonMapper method:

```
public static Object fromJsonToJavaObject(String jsonObject, Class<?> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
    return objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, clazz);
}
```

The Json mapper method should not be changed. It basically works. What does not work properly is the class in the middle with the part *??????.class*.

If I would pass here a class definition like *CorrectResultObject.class*, getData(...) would return an instance of CorrectResultObject, so this works. But this must be generic. Since I cannot pass something like *T.class*, I thought about passing *Object.class*, but then the final result (after casting, as seen above) is suddenly a LinkedHashMap?! I don't understand how the type information of **T** gets lost, since the class itself is instantiated with the T and the type erasure only happens in the method while conversion but not in the instantiated class?!

How do I have to write the class(es) to achieve that *getData(...)* returns an instance of the correct Generics type?

Comment: If it was possible to do that, ObjectMapper.readValue() would not force you to pass a Class. But it does. So it's necessary. So your own methods (getPreferencesData() and getData()) should also take one as argument, and pass it to the JsonMapper.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can modify `getData` method and pass the `Class` object to it to return the object of same class.
Something like this:

```
public T getData(String identifier, Class<? extends T> clazz) throws GeneralSecurityException, IOException {
    //do some stuff and get the content, which is a JSON 

    final T result = (T)JsonMapper.fromJsonToJavaObject(decryptedJson, clazz);

    return result;
}
```

Hope this helps

Comment: This is an acceptable approach. I wonder if I can get the information from the Generics type itself. But probably not.

Answer (score 1):

You said:

> The Json mapper method should not be changed. It basically works.

I would not say so. It needs to be parametrized as well just like `objectMapper.readValue`.

Change it to this:

```
public static <T> T fromJsonToJavaObject(String jsonObject, Class<T> clazz) throws JsonParseException, JsonMappingException, IOException
{
    return objectMapper.readValue(jsonObject, clazz);
}
```

And avoid casting here: `(T)JsonMapper.fromJsonToJavaObject`

Comment: With this approach, it cannot resolves T and I also get 'incompatible types, required java.lang.Object, found T'. If I change the JsonMapper itself to JsonMapper<T>, then I can't compile because of the static context.

Comment: You dont need to parametrize `JsonMapper`. And you of course need to pass Class<T> into `getData` and have it `T result = JsonMapper.fromJsonToJavaObject(decryptedJson, clazz);'